# using vcsi (video contact sheets) from within python code

Tags: python, command-line

I'm trying to call the video contact sheet module from within a python script, but for my life of it, I can't figure it out.

When I call it through command line, it works fine:

```
vcsi "C:\Users\testuser\Dropbox\Python\TestData\test.mp4" -t -w 850 -g 3x5 --end-delay-percent 20 -o c:\temp\output.png
```

How would I call the same process from with my python script (Python 3.5)?
I tried calling through subprocess, exec, etc, but I can't get it to run.

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run)

```
import subprocess as sub

args = ["vcsi", r"C:\users\testuser\dropbox\python\testdata\test.mp4", "-t", 
        "-w 850", "-g 3x5", "--end-delay-percent 20", r"-o C:\temp\output.png"]

cp = sub.run(args)
```